# How to split and search from array?

Tags: javascript, split, tostring

I'm trying to search for a name from phonebook and print the result out (`name: number`).

My resolution is to split a pre defined array `phonebook` and find a pre defined name `name` from the new array I get. The searched name should be saved to the pre defined `para2` with the number.

I can't make any changes to the code before `//Ad your code here` -tag. If I don't use `.toString` with the split, I get an error. If I use it, the code return nothing.

I'm guessing that my problem has something to do with string/array content, but cannot resolve this.

```
// Don't change this
let name = 'Mustafa';
let para2 = document.createElement('p');

let phonebook = [
  { name : 'Anne', number : '9065' },
  { name : 'Mustafa', number : '6888' },
  { name : 'Tina', number : '4312' },
]

// Add your code here
i = 0;
do {
  let splitContact = phonebook[i].toString().split('name : ', ', number : ');
  let nameListed = splitContact[0]
  let numberListed = splitContact[1]
  if (nameListed === name) {
    para2.textContent = nameListed.textContent + ': ' + numberListed.textContent;
    break;
  } else {
    para2.textContent = 'Contact not found.';
  }
  i++;
} while (i < phonebook.length);
```

Comment: you cannot use split on an object

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use `.toString()` on your objects. At the moment you are looping over your array using a do-while loop. This can be changed to a `while` loop as you know you'll need to iterate at least to the end of your array, however, you may stop looping earlier if you find your object. Using the `while` loop, you can loop over each object within your array to find if the object has a `.name` property equal to the search name. You can stop the loop once your object has been found:

```js
// Don't change this
let name = 'Mustafa';
  
let phonebook = [
  { name : 'Anne', number : '9065' },
  { name : 'Mustafa', number : '6888' },
  { name : 'Tina', number : '4312' },
];

let found = false;
let i = 0;
while(i < phonebook.length && !found) {
  const currentPerson = phonebook[i]; // get current object from phonebook
  if(currentPerson.name === name) { // use dot notation on the object, get it's name, and see if it equals the search name
    console.log(name +": " +currentPerson.number);
    found = true; // stop the loop
  } 
  i++;
}
// by this point we have looped through the entire array
if(!found) { // if found is still false, then the contact hasn't been found
  console.log("Contact not found.");
}
```

The above can also be done using higher-order functions, such as [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) on your `phonebook` array, which takes care of this logic for you:

```js
// Don't change this
let name = 'Mustafa';
  
let phonebook = [
  { name : 'Anne', number : '9065' },
  { name : 'Mustafa', number : '6888' },
  { name : 'Tina', number : '4312' },
];

const person = phonebook.find(o => o.name === name);

if(person) {
  console.log(person.name +": " +person.number);
} else {
  console.log("Contact not found.");
}
```

The find method takes a function, this function gets called on each element in your array. If it returns true for a given element in your array, the `.find()` method will return that element.

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked (I had to use the while version). I'm just starting and did not realise that "name:" and "number:" weren't a part of the actual string...

Comment: @tHelene no worries. Yeah, the object itself has the `name` and `number` property, that's the advantage of using objects, they allow you to store information by essentially giving it a "name"

Answer (score 0):

You just need to access the array element which is the object and the plug out the property which in your case is name and number.

You don't need to split anything.
Here's a minimal change to your code which should give you what you opt for

```
// Don't change this
let name = 'Mustafa';
let para2 = document.createElement('p');

let phonebook = [
  { name : 'Anne', number : '9065' },
  { name : 'Mustafa', number : '6888' },
  { name : 'Tina', number : '4312' },
]

// Add your code here
i = 0;
do {

  let nameListed =  phonebook[i].name
  let numberListed = phonebook[i].number
  if (nameListed === name) {
    para2.textContent = nameListed.textContent + ': ' + numberListed.textContent;
    break;
  } else {
    para2.textContent = 'Contact not found.';
  }
  i++;
} while (i < phonebook.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Without much context to the question, I'm wondering whether a `find` on the array would do the job?

`phonebook.find(x => x.name === name);`

This will either return the value found, or `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to do this

```
// Don't change this
let name = 'Mustafa';
let para2 = document.createElement('p');

let phonebook = [
  { name : 'Anne', number : '9065' },
  { name : 'Mustafa', number : '6888' },
  { name : 'Tina', number : '4312' },
]

let foundNumber = phonebook.find((phonebookEntry) => phonebookEntry.name === name)
if (foundNumber) {
    para2.textContent = `${foundNumber.name}: ${foundNumber.number}`;
} else {
    para2.textContent = 'Contact not found.';
}
```